# Adding total rows to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I define a Pandas DataFrame containing several deposit/withdrawal rows for different owners. I want to add a total row for each owner to totalize the deposits/withdrawals aswell as the yield amounts generated by each capital amount.

Here's the result of the code below:

[image: Code output]

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

OWNER = 'OWNER'
DEPWITHDR = 'DEP/WITHDR'
DATEFROM = 'DATE FROM'
DATETO = 'DATE TO'
CAPITAL = 'CAPITAL'
YIELD = 'YIELD AMT'
TOTAL = 'TOTAL'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    OWNER: 2*['JOE']+3*['ROB'],
    DEPWITHDR: [10000, 20000, 4000, 20000, -8000],
    CAPITAL: [10000, 30000, 4000, 24000, 16000],
    DATEFROM: ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    DATETO: ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-05'],
    YIELD: [100, 1200, 80, 240, 320]
    })

print('SOURCE DATAFRAME\n')
print(df)
print()

newDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=[OWNER, DEPWITHDR, CAPITAL, DATEFROM, DATETO, YIELD])

currentOwner = df.loc[1, OWNER]

# using groupby function to compute the two columns totals
dfTotal = df.groupby([OWNER]).agg({DEPWITHDR:'sum', YIELD:'sum'}).reset_index()
totalIndex = 0

# deactivating SettingWithCopyWarning caueed by totalRow[OWNER] += ' total'
pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', None)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if currentOwner == row[OWNER]:
        newDf = newDf.append({OWNER: row[OWNER], 
                              DEPWITHDR: row[DEPWITHDR],
                              CAPITAL: row[CAPITAL],
                              DATEFROM: row[DATEFROM],
                              DATETO: row[DATETO],
                              YIELD: row[YIELD]}, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        totalRow = dfTotal.loc[totalIndex]
        totalRow[OWNER] += ' total'
        newDf = newDf.append(totalRow, ignore_index=True)
        totalIndex += 1
        newDf = newDf.append({OWNER: '',
                              DEPWITHDR: '',
                             CAPITAL: '',
                              DATEFROM: '',
                              DATETO: '',
                              YIELD: ''}, ignore_index=True)
        newDf = newDf.append({OWNER: row[OWNER], 
                              DEPWITHDR: row[DEPWITHDR],
                              CAPITAL: row[CAPITAL],
                              DATEFROM: row[DATEFROM],
                              DATETO: row[DATETO],
                              YIELD: row[YIELD]}, ignore_index=True)
        currentOwner = row[OWNER]

totalRow = dfTotal.loc[totalIndex]
totalRow[OWNER] += ' total'
                
newDf = newDf.append(totalRow, ignore_index=True)

print('TARGET DATAFRAME\n')
print(newDf.fillna(''))
```

My question is: what is a better, more Pandas friendly, way, to obtain the desired result ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and `concat`:

```py
df_total = pd.concat((
    df,
    df.replace({o: o + ' total' for o in df[OWNER].unique()}).groupby(OWNER).agg({DEPWITHDR: sum, YIELD: sum}).reset_index())
).fillna('').reset_index().sort_values([OWNER, DATEFROM, DATETO])
```

In detail:

- `df.replace({o: o + ' total' for o in df[OWNER].unique()})`: replace each occurrence of the name of every owner with the name itself plus the string ' total' (e.g., 'JOE' -> 'JOE total'); so that the result of the `groupby` will have those values in the column `OWNER`.
- `groupby(OWNER).agg({DEPWITHDR: sum, YIELD: sum})`: get the sum of the column `DEPWITHDR` and `YIELD` per each owner.
- `pd.concat(...).fillna('').reset_index().sort_values([OWNER, DATEFROM, DATETO])`: concatenate the original DataFrame and that with the totals and then sort rows by column OWNER, than DATEFROM, than DATETO, so that the rows with the totals for each OWNER will be placed at the ends of the rows belonging to that owner (because they ends with `' total'`) and moreover the rows will be chronologically sorted by `DATEFROM`, `DATETO`.

Here `df_total`:

```sh
   index      OWNER  DEP/WITHDR CAPITAL   DATE FROM     DATE TO  YIELD AMT
0      0        JOE       10000   10000  2021-01-01  2021-01-01        100
1      1        JOE       20000   30000  2021-01-02  2021-01-05       1200
5      0  JOE total       30000                                       1300
2      2        ROB        4000    4000  2021-01-01  2021-01-02         80
3      3        ROB       20000   24000  2021-01-03  2021-01-03        240
4      4        ROB       -8000   16000  2021-01-04  2021-01-05        320
6      1  ROB total       16000                                        640
```

IMHO, I'd create a different DataFrame from each owner, with only his/her data, and then a summary DataFrame with totals for each owner. But, maybe, in your use case, this is the best solution.